# Basic SQL subqueries to get more than two table

Tags: sqlite

Hi I have three table named `airports`, `flights`, `checkin`. From this table I need to retrive some fields like:

```
flight.code,
flight.start_time,
flight.end_time,
flights.start_id,
flights.endid,
airports.name as sloc,
airports.name as eloc
```

The conditions are:

```
ckeckin.flight_id = flights.id,
airport.id = flights.startid, --for sloc
airports.id = flights.endid --for eloc
```

Comment: Please add the SQL you used to create the tables. You can get it with `.schema` at the SQLite prompt.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Tichodroma can you please tell me from where I  can get .schema.

Comment: Run `sqlite your_database_file .schema`.

Comment: Hi Am using Sqlite in IOS application so I have air.db and airDB.sqlite files only.Shall I paste here my schema of tables

Comment: Yes, please do this. But please edit your question.

Comment: In Airport fileds are Id,city,citycode,countrycode,countryname and in Chekin table fileds are id,user-id,flight_id,type in flights code,name,start_time,end_time,startid,endid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select flights.code, flights.start_time, flights.end_time, 
flights.start_id, flights.endid, 
a.name as sloc, b.name as eloc
from flights
left join airports a on (flights.start_id = a.id)
left join airports b on (flights.endid = b.id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen It retrieves all data from flights but i need to retrieve only checkin.flight_id =flight.id so shall I use the condition like (flights.start_id=a.id and checkin.id=flights.id) It will work?

Comment: Or how to check chekin table also

Comment: The `LEFT JOINs `above shouldn't be changed. Just add an extra `WHERE` clause to get what you need:
`WHERE checkin.id = flights.id` and you should be fine.